# Standard key/value datastore for unix

Tags: database

I know about the **key/value** libraries for unix (**berkeleydb**, **gdbm**, **redis**... ). But before I start coding, I wonder if there is a standard tool for unix that would allow me to perform the following operations:

```
$ tool -f datastore.db put "KEY" "VALUE"
$ tool -f datastore.db put -f file_key_values.txt
$ tool -f datastore.db get "KEY"
$ tool -f datastore.db get -f file_keys.txt
$ tool -f datastore.db remove "KEY"
$ etc...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard tool for that. Except for `grep`/`awk`/`sed` etc. But using this you will need to care about lot of other issues like locking, format, special characters, etc.

I suggest to use [`sqlite`](http://www.sqlite.org/). Define a simple table and then create `tool_get()` and `tool_put()` shell functions. `sqlite` is portable, fast.

You will get extra flexibility for free. You can define constrains, index to tweak your script or use that DB in other languages some day.

Comment: Thank you . I quickly wrote a tool with the sqlite API. It works fine.

Answer (score 16):

If your database is small enough, then you can use the filesystem. The advantage of this approach is that it's very low-tech, and will work everywhere with very little code. If the keys are composed of printable characters and do not contain `/`, then you can use them as file names:

```sh
put () { key=$1; value=$2; printf %s "$value" >"datastore.db/$key"; }
get () { key=$1; cat "datastore.db/$key"; }
remove () { key=$1; rm "datastore.db/$key"; }
```

To accommodate arbitrary keys, use a checksum of the key as the file name, and optionally store a copy of the key (unless you're happy with not being able to list the keys or tell what the key is for a given entry).

```sh
put () {
  key=$1; value=$2; set $(printf %s "$key" | sha1sum); sum=$1
  printf %s "$key" >"datastore.db/$sum.key"
  printf %s "$value" >"datastore.db/$sum.value"
}
get () {
  key=$1; set $(printf %s "$key" | sha1sum); sum=$1
  cat "datastore.db/$1.value"
}
remove () {
  key=$1; set $(printf %s "$key" | sha1sum); sum=$1
  rm "datastore.db/$1.key" "datastore.db/$1.value"
}
```

Note that the toy implementations above are not the whole story: they do not have any useful [transactional property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) such as atomicity. The basic filesystem operations such as file creation and renaming are atomic however, and it is possible to build atomic versions of the functions above.

These direct-to-filesystem implementations are suitable with typical filesystems only for small databases, up to a few thousand files. Beyond this point, most filesystems have a hard time coping with large directories. You can adapt the scheme to larger databases by using a layered layout. For example, instead of storing all the files in one directory, store them in separate subdirectories based on the first few characters of their names. This is what [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) does, for example: its objects, indexed by SHA-1 hashes, are stored in files called `.git/objects/01/2345679abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567`. Other examples of programs that use a semantic layering are the web caching proxies [Wwwoffle](https://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/wwwoffle/) and [polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/); both store the cached copy of a page found at a URL in a file called `www.example.com/HASH` where HASH is some encoding of some hash of the URL.¹

Another source of inefficiency is that most filesystems waste a lot of space when storing small files — there is a waste of up to 2kB per file on typical filesystems, independently of the size of the file.

If you choose to go with a real database, you don't need to forego the convenience of transparent filesystem access. There are several [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystems to [access databases](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=DatabaseFileSystems) including Berkeley DB (with [Jeff Garzik's dbfs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/fuse/dbfs.git/)), Oracle (with [Oracle DBFS](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbfs-11gr2)), MySQL (with [mysqlfs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlfs/)), etc.

¹ 
<sub>For an URL like `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21943/standard-key-value-datastore-for-unix`, Polipo uses the file `unix.stackexchange.com/M0pPbpRufiErf4DLFcWlhw==`, with an added header inside the file indicating the actual URL in clear text; the file name is the base64 encoding of the MD5 hash (in binary) of the URL. Wwwoffle uses the file `http/unix.stackexchange.com/DM0pPbpRufiErf4DLFcWlhw`; the name of the file is a home-grown encoding of the MD5 hash, and a companion file `http/unix.stackexchange.com/UM0pPbpRufiErf4DLFcWlhw` contains the URL.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

[`dbmutil`](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/src/dbmtools.man.html) might get you what you want.  It has shell utilities for the operations you describe in the question.  I wouldn't say it's exactly standard, but it does have the facilities you want.

Answer (score 7):

Since you named it, the standard redis client has a command line interface through `redis-cli`. Some examples from `redis-cli -h`:

```
 cat /etc/passwd | redis-cli -x set mypasswd
 redis-cli get mypasswd
 redis-cli -r 100 lpush mylist x
```

(And if you want to access the db through the filesystem you can use sockets with `-s`. A tool that would read the db index directly on each invocation would be kind of very inefficient.)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use [GDBM GNU Database](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)

Tested on a debian based OS (buster):

```
apt install gdbmtool
```

Using from bash gdbmtool read command from stdin:

```
$ gdbmtool -s datastore.gdbm <<<"store KEY VALUE"
  # load from file (rows format "key: value")
$ gdbmtool -s datastore.gdbm < <(awk -F: '{print "store "$1" "$2}'  file_key_values.txt)
$ gdbmtool -s datastore.gdbm <<< "fetch KEY"
  # fetch many keys (only values outputed in order)
$ gdbmtool -s datastore.gdbm < <(awk '{print "fetch "$1}' file_keys.txt)
$ gdbmtool -s datastore.gdbm <<<"delete KEY"
$ gdbmtool -s datastore.gdbm list
```

More in `man gdbmtool`

Dump

```
$ gdbm_dump datastore.gdbm > mydump.txt
```

Load dump

```
$ gdbm_load mydump.txt datastore.gdbm
```

Answer (score 2):

There's `recfiles` from `recutils`

https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/

recsel, recset, recfmt, rec2csv