# File backed, key value store implemented with posix utilities

Tags: shell-script, shell, utilities

I imagine this is a pretty common thing to do.

Which posix utility for reads, which for writes? What are the most common file formats to do this with?

Is inplace modification possible?

My first thought was to use json and jq, but I'm interested in embracing the unix philosophy

**Edit**:

> I don't think there is a standard tool for that. Except for `grep/awk/sed` etc. But using this you will need to care about lot of other issues like locking, format, special characters, etc. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21950/551103

What if didn't care about "locking, format, special characters" at all? Can someone give a minimalist implementation with `grep/awk/sed`

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21943/standard-key-value-datastore-for-unix I guess implementing it with filesystem is the way to go

Comment: `grep`/`awk`/`sed` are line-based text utilities. Does that mean that your keys and values are meant to be sequences of 0 or more characters other than NUL and newline encoded in the locale's charset and whose length in bytes is < 1023?

Comment: FYIW, zsh associative arrays (whose keys and values can be any sequence of bytes) can be tied to gdbm DBs.

Comment: Um... Using `jq` would be "embracing the Unix philosophy" as much as using any other tool. You can make it easy for yourself by using an existing tool specialised in reading and writing the data you are interested in, in the format that allows your data to be expressed most conveniently.  You have not mentioned if you deal with simple strings, key+value pairs, or data with a more complicated structure, e.g. arrays, many-to-many mappings, etc.  Rewriting tools for the sake of rewriting them in a specific language strikes me as masochistic.

Comment: Note that you can invoke `perl` or the interpreter of any other proper interpreted programming language in shells, and most of those programming languages can take the code to interpret on the command line or from a file descriptor. `perl` is ubiquitous (a lot more common than systems with the full POSIX toolchest let alone with fully compliant tools) and has support for (de)serialising its data structures or tying them with on-disk DB files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, just simple human readable config

Comment: @Kusalananda I kind of meant portable, its annoying to have to install dependencies.

Comment: Then why not just use shell code that contain variable assignments (and comments)? Most humans understand thinks like `var='value...'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It wouldn't preserve state between sessions

Comment: You can always dump the values of the variables as shell assignments into the file.

Comment: Why not just create files in the filesystem? The filename is the key, the file content is the value. The are code examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688849/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts In the (at the moment (2023-11-10)) third answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/691023).

Comment: @rathier The appeal of a file of `key=value` lines is that it is more human readable. But I agree the filesystem is a good way to implement this. also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21979/551103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For alphanumeric key-values:

```bash
kvfile="kvfile"

put() {
    if grep -q "^${1}=" "$kvfile"; then
        sed -i "s/^${1}=.*$/${1}=${2}/" "$kvfile"
    else
        echo "${1}=${2}" >> "$kvfile"
    fi
}

get() {
    grep "^${1}=" "$kvfile" | awk -F= '{printf "%s", $2}'
}
```

Martin Kealey actually knows how to script `sed` and `awk` and suggests:

```
put() {
    sed -i "/^$1=/{ h ; s/=.*/=$2/ ; } ; $ { p; g; /./d; s/^$/$1=$2/ ; }" "$kvfile";
}

get() { 
    awk -F= -vk="$1" '$1 == k{ print $2 }' "$kvfile";
}
```

Comment: `sed -i` is not POSIX, using variable data inside a sed script is an ACE vulnerability. `awk -F ... $2` breaks if values contain =, leaving parameter expansions unquoted has a very special meaning in POSIX sh, `A && B || C` cannot be used in place of proper `if then else fi`, behaviour of `echo` is unspecified if arguments may contain backslashes, the first argument of `printf` is the format, shouldn't be variable external data...

Comment: Since you are using `$1` unquoted, this would split the 1st argument's value on whitespace (by default), and then apply filename globbing on the split-up bits.  The first of the resulting words would be used as a regular expression by `grep` while any other part would be used as input filenames. On the other hand, with `sed`, the value would be used as a regular expression as-is.  In the `sed` calls, you limit the number of valid substrings that can occur in `$1` and `$2` since you are using them as the replacement of a `s` command.  They can therefore not contain strings like `\1` or `&`.

Comment: What's missing is proper quoting and handling of the shell arguments, and encoding of the user-supplied data (both keys and values).  Suggestions for encoding scheme: JSON or base64.  `jq` handles both of these.

Comment: The quotes in the `sed` command are quite scrambled (and they don't nest). Also the lack of quotes around `$kvfile` will mean this breaks when `kvfile` contains some names. I suggest `put() { sed -i "/^$1=/{ h ; s/=.*/=$2/ ; } ; $ { p; g; /./d; s/^$/$1=$2/ ; }" "$kvfile" ; }` in place of the existing grep+sed+echo combo (or something else if you don't have `sed -i`), and `get() { awk -F= -vk="$1" '$1 == k { print $2 }' "$kvfile" ; }` in place of the grep+awk combo