# A && B || C vs if then else fi

Tags: shell-script, shell

Stéphane [commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761036/551103) that

> `A && B || C` cannot be used in place of proper `if then else fi`

Can someone explain what's the difference?

Comment: C may run when A is true. Explained in [a shellcheck rule](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015)

Comment: @tinystone Thanks. `if A is true but B is false, C will run.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to make a mistake in cases like `A && B || C`.

They are almost universally "write only" - once you wrote such compound statement and it works - it is difficult to change some parts of such statement without loosing the whole logic.

If `A` or `B` commands are not a one-word commands - such compound statement can become extremely long and difficult to read, since you would need to horizontally scroll the line.

If `A` or `B` - are commands with parameters, then you will have problems with finding `&&` and `||` in the long lines of words. Again difficulties to understand and maintain.

If you have something like

```
make && run_test
```

That is fine. But that is actually an extent of usability. Anything more - better be rewritten to `if then fi`

Comment: You cant use \ to break `A && B || C` across multiple lines. I'm use to programming with monads so this is natural https://topaz.github.io/paste/#XQAAAQBOAAAAAAAAAAAFGTH0Q/5dPoIBanK0lQdPubviXoHoVCPrBYPgbwKEW/0peR3Vnsq+h2ewq3AYM9Gst+SO2PKsF3QD/UIcyt//8XYQAA==

Comment: @TomHuntington  Bash lets you break lines immediately after `&&` and `||`, just like it does with pipe `|`. No bashslashes required. If the B and C commands are wrapped in `{ }` or `( )` they can be multi-line as for any other pipeline. Not saying this is a good idea, only that syntax and long lines are not the issue here.